# How to pass on the Target to another macro in Excel events?

Tags: excel, vba, events

How to pass on the Target to another macro in Excel events? For just the elegant purpose, I would like to use the following structure, which does not work now.

`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   GoToAnotherMacro(Target)
End Sub

Sub GoToAnotherMacro(Target)
'here my code where I can use Target i.e:
MsgBox "value: " & Target.Value
End Sub`

Comment: You should not put parentheses around the parameter for calling a sub. `GoToAnotherMacro Target` should solve the issue. Read http://www.cpearson.com/excel/byrefbyval.aspx - "Converting A ByRef Parameter To ByVal" for what are the parenthesis doing in this case.

Comment: What about called Sub GoToAnotherMacro? Should I use GoToAnotherMacro() or GoToAnotherMacro(Target) or GoToAnotherMacro Target? PS. The link you pasted is dead.

Comment: You should use `GoToAnotherMacro Target` for calling the SUB within your `Private Sub Worksheet_Change`. Parentheses around arguments which are passed to SUBs will lead to pass those arguments ByVal instead ByRef.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest the use of a global variable:

1) Define a global variable:

```
Dim RangeSupp As Range
```

2) In your procedure, pass the local Target to your global variable

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set RangeSupp = Target
    GoToAnotherMacro RangeSupp
End Sub
```

3) Enjoy your target in your other macro

```
Sub GoToAnotherMacro(Target As Range)
MsgBox Target.Value
End Sub
```

**NOTE:**  Global variables are put on top of all the code, *outside* any other Function or Sub. The global variable is preserved in the stack even outside the single scope of the macro. That is the reason why you will be able to pass a global variable from a macro to the other. On the other hand, now you're not able (you get "Object required error") because the `Target` object, once outside its scope in `Worksheet_Change`, is removed from the stack so it gets back to its default value (`Nothing`), causing the problem you have in your above code.